# how to make formula of variance?

Tags: variance

this is my formula

```
Else : cmb1.Text = "Rata - Rata"
        ' hitung rata-rata
        rerata = jumlah / lstData.Items.Count

        ' menampilkan hasil rerata ke text box
        txtRerata.Text = rerata.ToString

        cmb1.Text = "Variansi" Then
        'inisialisasi variabel variansi
        Xi = lstData.Items.Item(index:=counter)

        ' hitung variansi
        For counter = 0 To lstData.Items.Count - 1
            variansi = (Xi - rerata) * (Xi - rerata)
        Next

        'menampilkan hasil variansi ke text box
        txtVariansi.Text = variansi.ToString
    End If
```

What's the problem with this ?
I can't get the result.
thanks

What if like this ?

ElseIf cmb1.Text = "Variansi" Then
            'inisialisasi variabel variansi
            Xi = 0

```
        ' iterasi sejumlah item dari listbox
        For counter = 0 To lstData.Items.Count - 1
            Xi = Xi + ((lstData.Items.Item(counter) - rerata) ^ 2)
        Next

        'kalkulasi variansi dan simpangan baku
        variansi = Xi / (txtN.Text - 1)
        SD = Math.Sqrt(variansi)
        txtSD.Text = SD.ToString

        'menampilkan hasil variansi ke text box
        txtVariansi.Text = variansi.ToString
```

can you help me ?

Answer (score 1):

> The variance  is defined as the sum of the squared distances of each
>   term in the distribution from the mean, divided by the number of terms
>   in the distribution.

You need to divide `variansi` by `lstData.Items.Count`